# Active Storage is outputting image metadata in HTML

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I am creating a form where a user can change the images they uploaded. The problem is the form to edit the images is displaying the image metadata along with the images that have been uploaded. Alongside the images, in the HTML page it outputs the following:

```
[#<ActiveStorage::Attachment id: 3, name: "image", record_type: "Space", record_id: 1, blob_id: 3, created_at: "2018-08-20 00:52:57">,
```

How do I prevent it from displaying the above data?

Here is the relevant code
html.erb file that displays the images

```
<div>
  <% if @space.image.attached? %>
      <%= @space.image.each do |image| %>
      <%= image_tag image  %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Model

```
class Space < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  has_many_attached :image

end
```

Controller

```
class SpacesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show]

  def index
    @spaces = current_user.spaces
  end

  def new
    @space = current_user.spaces.build
  end

  def create
    @space = current_user.spaces.build(space_params)
    if @space.save
      redirect_to listing_space_path(@space), notice: "Saved..."
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Something went wrong..."
      render :new
    end
  end

  def show
  end

  def update
    if @space.update(space_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Saved!"
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Something went wrong. Please check your submission and try again."
    end
      redirect_back(fallback_location: request.referer)
  end

  private
    def space_params
        params.require(:space).permit(:name, :description, image: [])
    end

end
```

Comment: `<%= @space.image.each do |image| %>` remove the `=` at the start, that outputs the result, and the return value of `each` is the collection it was iterating

Comment: As @SimpleLime has mentioned remove the `=` from <%= @space.image.each do |image| %>. `<%= %>` will print the contents, hence you're seeing the `object`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On:

```
<%= @space.image.each do |image| %>
```

Remove the `=` after the `<%`.

On an ERB tag, the equals sign will print the result of that line. It is printing the `.inspect` on the image object.

Answer (score 0):

For people using haml and running into this issue:

```
= @user.images.each do |image|
    = image_tag image.variant(resize_to_limit: [300, 220])
```

becomes

```
# replace = sign
- @user.images.each do |image|
    = image_tag image.variant(resize_to_limit: [300, 220])
```